# Why iPhone 4/S max-device-width is 480 and not 320?

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I'm a little confused about targeting iPhones devices (in this case 4/S).
I've read that no matter the orientation, the Apple phone will always return the DEVICE-WIDTH value in PORTRAIT (meaning 320px for iPhone 4).

Said this, if the device it's always returning a 320px, why almost all media queries I looked online for this devide take into account the 480px (if this value is not supposed to be returned)?

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

  /* your CSS here */
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: @BoltClock: Looks like they've stumbed across learning the difference between device-width and width: [first result on google](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml)

Comment: it can be related to the current known values of iPhones' widths (320pt, 375pt, 414pt), which covers the currently known sizes of iPhone4, 5, 6, and 6+. that is the reason why you need to consider various widths between that range when you optimize your website – if the width becomes bigger then 480, that means the device is in landscape orientation, so that is where that amount comes from.

Comment: that media query is from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ Choose Iphone devices, and then look for iphone 4 code (landscape or portrait). There, they use the 480px max-device-width. So is it wrong that iPhone returns only the width of portrait mode (even in landscape mode)?